# Post back cotrol

Tags: asp.net-2.0

How to get the control or control Id which caused the post back in asp.net 2.0 page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a collection:

```
Request.Form
```

That is passed back to form. So iterating through keys you obtain name of controls. But these names matches Control.UniqueId, but not Control.ID

Comment: IS there a fuction called GetPostBackControl() which returns the control.. i found this in web.

Comment: No there is no such method, it is concerned with possibility to create dynamicaly as ASP.Net controls as client-side-jscript posyback controls. But good news - it is easy to write it, create iteration over tree of children controls and select those who supports IPostBackDataHandler interface.